# Linux terminal shortcut

Tags: terminal, shortcut

I wanted to use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> keys to open the terminal but I got a message that there is no task for this shortcut and I just added "terminal" word there and now whenever I want to use this shortcut I get this error message:

"Failed to execute child process “terminal” (No such file or directory)"

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using "ctrl + alt + t"?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing what desktop environment you are using - there are lots which run on Linux.

Comment: I use Lubuntu and instead of using in Terminal cd Documents/folder-name wanted to use Fn+F4 to open Terminal directly from that path and now get error!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `terminal` command, I believe you are looking for `x-terminal-emulator`, assuming this is a Linux-based operating system (might not apply for all of them).

Comment: I use Lubuntu and instead of using in Terminal cd Documents/folder-name wanted to use Fn+F4 to open Terminal directly from that path and now get error!